# Как в цикле for ввести числа от 0 до 9, НЕ используя тело цикла?

Tags: php

Как ввести в цикле `for` числа от `0` до `9`, НЕ используя тело цикла?

То есть выглядеть должно вот так:

```
for(…) {

    // здесь пусто

}
```

Comment: какой в этом смысл?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В цикле for() только первое выражение вычисляется в момент компиляции. Остальные вычисляются в момент интерпретации:

```
for($i = 0; print $i, $i++ < 9;)
```

Результат:

```
0123456789
```